# My answer to this simple question is wrong but I don't know why

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

I'm self-studying abstract algebra, and prior to fields there's a brief section on vector spaces. One of the questions asks:

"Is $U = \{(a, b-1, c)| a, b, c \in F \}$ a subspace of $F^3$? ($F$ a field)"

I figured that the answer was yes because $(a, b-1, c) + (d, e-1, f) = ((a+d), (b+e-1) -1, (c+f))$ and $k(a, b-1, c) = (ka, (kb -k +1) - 1, kc)$

so the set would be closed under addition and scalar multiplication. 
Why, then, is this answer wrong? It's apparently not a subspace? 
I feel like I must have some crucial misunderstanding about this topic, and I don't have anyone else to help me. What's the gap in my understanding?

Comment: Are you sure it's written correctly? As you described it, $U$ is all of $F^3$, which is indeed a subspace.

Comment: Here's exactly what it says: "(1.) Which of the following are subspaces of $F^3$? (c) $U = \{(a, b -1, c) | a, b, c \in F \}$

Comment: @Nethesis Since $b-1\in F$ you can write 
$$U=\{(a,\tilde b,c) | a,\tilde b,c\in F\} \stackrel{\text{def.}}= F^3$$

Comment: I much thought the same! I could not see any reason how it couldn't be all of $F^3$, but that seemed too stupid to say given the "answer".

Comment: Is the source available online?

Comment: I don't think so, it's "An introduction to Abstract Algebra, V2" by W. Keith Nicholson.

Comment: Your reasoning is corrrect (of course you need also to show that $U$ is non-empty, don't you?), however arkert/AlexR are also correct and also your calculation is based essentially on the fact that any element of $F$ can be written as one less than another element ...

Comment: I would have thought it would be assumed, to be honest, because surely $U$ is non-empty so long as $F$ is?